# Как сделать кнопку "поделится"?

Tags: java, android

[image: Пример]

Хочу сделать кнопку поделится. Когда пользователь будет нажимать на неё, должно высвечиваться  следующие. Как это сделать? Также хочется, что бы был определенный тест, например
Приложение name, скачивай от сюда - ссылка.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Приложение name, скачивай от сюда - ссылка");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Поделиться"));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 public void newShare(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "текст");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Поделится ^-^"));
}
```

Comment: ВНИМАНИЕ! В коде ошибка, нужно intent.setType("text/plain"); О чем думали те кто голосовал за ответ? Плюс ("ПоделитЬся").